# BSD (& Linux) tput - basic interoperable color setup

Tags: terminal, colors, bsd, tput

Can anyone on ***BSD with GUI** please confirm, that the below works on a BSD system correctly or not?

I was trying to create a virtual *BSD test box, but ended up unsuccessful. So, I drained some available resources for correct `tput` sequences on *BSD... Thank you!

---

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if tput setaf > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Linux tput
    tput_number_of_colors=$(tput colors)
    tput_cmd_set_fg_color='tput setaf'
    tput_bold=$(tput bold)
    tput_reset=$(tput sgr0)
elif tput AF > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # BSD tput
    tput_number_of_colors=$(tput Co)
    tput_cmd_set_fg_color='tput AF'
    tput_bold=$(tput smso)
    tput_reset=$(tput me)
else
    # black & white console, or no tput
    tput_number_of_colors=2
    tput_cmd_set_fg_color=
    tput_bold=
    tput_reset=
fi

tput_test ()
# this function uses the above to test tput capability of the terminal
{
    { command -v tput && [ "$tput_number_of_colors" -ge 8 ] && $tput_cmd_set_fg_color 1 && echo "$tput_bold"; } > /dev/null 2>&1
}

if tput_test; then
    # example of bold color definition
    color_red=$tput_bold$($tput_cmd_set_fg_color $color_red_id)
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: **`s/smso/so/`** (termcap-names are always 2 characters).  The [terminfo(5)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page is the place to go for answering your question as stated.

The manual page shows this:

```
      enter_bold_mode             bold      md     turn on bold (extra
                                                   bright) mode
```

so that **`md`** would be used for turning on *bold* mode.  **`smso`** (terminfo) or **`so`** (termcap) turns on *standout mode*, which you can see later in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Highlighting_-Underlining_-and-Visible-Bells) is not necessarily the same as *bold*:

> If your terminal has one or more kinds of display attributes, these can
> be represented in a number of different ways.  You  should  choose  one
> display  form  as  *standout  mode*,  representing a good, high contrast,
> easy-on-the-eyes, format for  highlighting  error  messages  and  other
> attention  getters.   (If  you  have a choice, *reverse video* plus *half-
> bright* is good, or *reverse video* alone.)  The sequences  to  enter  and
> exit  *standout  mode*  are given as **`smso`** and **`rmso`**, respectively.  If the
> code to change into or out of *standout mode*  leaves  one  or  even  two
> blank  spaces  on  the screen, as the TVI 912 and Teleray 1061 do, then
> **`xmc`** should be given to tell how many spaces are left.

Comment: So, according to that page bold should be changed to `tput_bold=$(tput md)`, right?

Comment: The wood is being missed for the trees, here.  This whole approach doesn't work.  It isn't distinguishing between Linux and BSD in the first place.  It's trying to distinguish between terminfo and termcap `tput`.  But it doesn't work.  `tput setaf` succeeds on a termcap `tput` on FreeBSD (because it's seen as `tput se`), and _both_ `tput setaf` and `tput AF` fail on a terminfo `tput` on OpenBSD (because not enough arguments are supplied to the command).

Comment: OP's question was whether it would work.  The answer was "no" (there's additional checks OP could make, but that wasn't the actual question).

Comment: The rationale for why it is no misses the wood for the trees, though.  It's not because of a difference between standout and boldface.  It's because even the underlying idea of a Linux/BSD dichotomy is wrong here, and the commands don't behave in the ways that would be necessary for the tests to work.